# How can I sort x,y co-ordinates from a list of dictionary?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I need to sort a list of dictionaries by x and y co-ordinates.

My list is:

```
xy_list = [{'x':40,'y':50},{'x':40,'y':10},{'x':40,'y':50},{'x':20,'y':10},{'x':20,'y':30},{'x':10,'y':10}]
```

The desired output is:

```
xy_list = [{'x':10,'y':10},{'x':20,'y':10},{'x':20,'y':30},{'x':40,'y':10},{'x':40,'y':30},{'x':40,'y':50}]
```

How do I get this sorted?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to sort your data like this:

```
xy_list = [{'x':40,'y':50},{'x':40,'y':10},{'x':40,'y':50},{'x':20,'y':10},{'x':20,'y':30},{'x':10,'y':10}]
xy_list.sort(key=lambda item:item['x'])
```

the `key` defines a way to get the item to compare, in your case you need to get an item from a dict so here `item['x']` you can write what ever your key is,`x` or `y` in your case

Comment: i need to sort the list  with the 'y' co-ordinate also.

Comment: `sorted(xy_list, key = lambda i: (i['x'], i['y']))` use this for sorting x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to dataframe and use sort_values and then convert to dict by records.

```
In [13]: xy_list = [{'x':40,'y':50},{'x':40,'y':10},{'x':40,'y':50},{'x':20,'y':10},{'x':20,'y':30},{'x':10,'y':10}]

In [14]: import pandas as pd

In [15]: df = pd.DataFrame(xy_list)

In [16]: new_df = df.sort_values(['x','y'])

In [17]: new_df.to_dict('records')
Out[17]:
[{'x': 10, 'y': 10},
 {'x': 20, 'y': 10},
 {'x': 20, 'y': 30},
 {'x': 40, 'y': 10},
 {'x': 40, 'y': 50},
 {'x': 40, 'y': 50}]
```